# Embed VBA macro in R

Tags: r, excel, vba

How to embed/execute excel VBA macro in R ? 
I have below SUB which I want o execute from R console.

```
Sub splitinto99()
Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, vArrIn As Variant, vArrOut As Variant
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
vArrIn = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
ReDim vArrOut(1 To 24, 1 To Int(LastRow / 24) + 1)
For X = 0 To LastRow - 1
vArrOut(1 + (X Mod 24), 1 + Int(X / 24)) = vArrIn(X + 1, 1)
Next
Range("B1").Resize(24, UBound(vArrOut, 2)) = vArrOut
End Sub
```

Comment: There does not appear to be a mechanism for evaluating VBA code in R nor does there appear to be any package that offers such support. You'll probably be better off ditching the VBA and re-coding using R.

Comment: Most of use have not used VBA for a long time (if ever). Tell us how you would execute it from a system command window.

Comment: Are we to assume you have an instance of Excel open with the file in question already open?

Comment: I can understand people wanting to execute R code in Excel. But why would you want to execute Excel-VBA code in R?

Comment: I have below R code which generates CSV table with values in a single column .I need to divide the column values into multiple columns with equal number of rows.I'm using VBA to do that.  `library(randomForest)
set.seed(123)
random81=randomForest(Zonal.Price~.-ZONEID,data=train8,n.tree=500)
pred=predict(random81,newdata=test8)

quant=NULL
for (i in (1:24))
   { quant=qnorm((1:99)/100,pred[i]) 
      write.table(quant,"pred.csv",row.names = FALSE,append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE, sep = ", ")
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to put the probabilities in columns & rows without using VBA . by creating list and for loop.

```
probs <- seq(.01,.99,.01)
wlm <- plm <- list()
for(i in seq_along(probs)){
wlm[[i]] <- lm(Zonal.Price~.-ZONEID-timestamp,data=train9)
plm[[i]] <- predict(wlm[[i]],newdata=test9)
}
write.csv(plm,"predlm.csv")
```